# Docker compose PHP version error but docker-compose.yml without image TAG image

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, microservices, lumen

I am doing a microservice course and I have downloaded this project from the website course but the project isn't working.

I have a PHP Lumen project and this is its docker-compose.yml, I had updated its composer dependencies before run because my computer has only PHP 8.1:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    web-academico:
        build: ./php-web
        volumes:
          - ./php-web/:/app
          - type: bind
            source: ./php-web.sh
            target: /app/entrypoint.sh
        working_dir: /app
        command: sh ./entrypoint.sh
        ports:
          - 8080:8080
```

And when I run this docker-composer, I have this message error:

```
Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0". You are running 8.0.21. in /app/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 24
```

I tried to put the TAG "image: php:8.1.0-fpm" but isn't work.

The entrypoint.sh is blank.

How can I solve it? And why docker is run without TAG image in docker-compose.yml?

Comment: What is in the Dockerfile?  The `volumes:` overwrite everything in the image's `/app` directory, which probably hides the installation Composer did, and `working_dir:` and `command:` similarly duplicate the Dockerfile `WORKDIR` and `CMD` directives.  Does deleting everything except `build:` and `ports:` make a difference?

Comment: If you need a specific tag, you can [use `build:` and `image:` together](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#image) to specify the name and tag of the built image.  Do _not_ specify `image: php`, give your application a unique name (maybe include your name in it, even if you don't have a Docker Hub account).

Comment: Tahnk you, I've forgot about Dockerfile and you comment helped me a lot, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've forgot about Dockerfile and the configuration was in that file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).